# Update ng-repeat from another Angular controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I load by default a list from the *Clash of Clans* API which returns a JSON response. Everything goes well inside my first controller (`MainCtrl`).

Then, I added a form to search a clan by its ID (`SearchCtrl`).

I can get the value passed by the form but now I'm trying to update the list inside my `ng-repeat` directive `member in memberList` which is in  `MainCtrl`.

I googled my problem many times but no solutions found. And I do not want 
to use the `$rootScope`. I'm sure that there is an another less dirty way to achieve what I want.

Here is my HTML and Angular code

HTML:

```
<form class="uk-form" name="searchClanform" ng-controller="SearchCtrl" novalidate>              
  <input type="text" name="idCLan" class="uk-form-width-medium"
    placeholder="Eg. PP8JC9RQ"
    ng-model="searchClanform.idClan"
    ng-pattern="/([A-Za-z0-9]){1,8}/"
    required>
  <button href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary"
    ng-disabled="searchClanform.$invalid"
    ng-click="getClanFromForm()">Rechercher <i class="uk-icon-search"></i></button>
</form>
<section class="uk-container uk-container-center" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="uk-table uk-table-condensed uk-table-striped uk-table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="member in memberList">
      <td>
        {{member.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{member.league.name | LeagueEnToFr}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{member.expLevel}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{member.trophies}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

AngularJS:

```
CocApp.service("CocAppServices", function($http) {
    this.getAllMembers = function(clanId, callback) {
        $http.get("clan/" + clanId).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data.memberList);
            //$scope.memberList = data.memberList;
            callback(data.memberList);
        });
    };
});
var MainCtrl = CocApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, CocAppServices) {
    $scope.getAllMembers = function(clanId) {
        CocAppServices.getAllMembers(clanId,function(data) {
          $scope.memberList = data;
        });
    };
    $scope.getAllMembers("PP8JC9RQ");
});
var SearchCtrl = CocApp.controller("SearchCtrl", function($scope, CocAppServices) {     
    $scope.getClanFromForm = function(){
        console.log("Formulaire de recherche soumis !!");
        console.log($scope.searchClanform.idClan);
        /* Here I want to update my ng-repeat directive from MainCtrl */
    }
});
```

Hope I was clear in my problem, 
regards.

Comment: Simplest quick way right now without completely rewriting service is to use a broadcast event

Comment: There is no need to show your server side code, this actually just makes your code harder to read.

Comment: @bto.rdz ok i'll delete it

Comment: @akio as a Tip, I really wanted to help you, but you include a lot of code that is not necessary, so I find it boring to read your question, you should try just the necessary code, that way you will get tons of answers.

Comment: Code truncated @bto.rdz hope it's as short as possible

Answer (score 0):

Normally Angular has watchers that automatically triggers a digest cycle once the scope has been updated. This is a fundamental in angular's 2 way data binding.

It is not very clear to me what your question is exactly but here is what will help you :

UI should update once the $scope.memberList values have changed. In the event that it does not update. You can always call $scope.apply() to trigger a digest cycle manually.

I think what you are trying to do is to search again for a new ID. So I imagine the code you want where your comment is should look like this :

```
CocAppServices.getAllMembers(clanId,function(data) {
$scope.$parent.memberList = data;
        });
```

This assumes of course that you set your searchCtrl as a child of the mainCtrl which should be the case for an operation like this.

Or even simpler. get rid of your search controller and put the getClanFromForm function in the mainCtrl

Comment: Does $scope.$parent is for nested controller, no ?! If yes I don't have nested controler.. Maybe I should ?!

Comment: And yes @Hugo I try to search again for a new ID

Comment: I think there is no other way then using the root scope if you dont have nested controllers. Besides think of the practical application of the search functionality, you don't want this to be logically separated from where you are trying to show this data